# Improving my way of showing $\sin^212^\circ+\sin^221^\circ+\sin^239^\circ+\sin^248^\circ=1+\sin^29^\circ+\sin^218^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

This problem is from 1904 and was given to students studying for the Cambridge and Oxford entry examinations. My solution is presented below, but I am of the opinion that it can be improved. All ideas welcome.

> Show that
> $$\sin^{2}{12^{\circ}}+\sin^{2}{21^{\circ}}+\sin^{2}{39^{\circ}}+\sin^{2}{48^{\circ}}=1+\sin^{2}{9^{\circ}}+\sin^{2}{18^{\circ}}$$

**A solution**

$$\begin{align}
\sin^{2}{12^{\circ}}=\sin^{2}{(30^{\circ}-18^{\circ})} 
&=(\sin{30^{\circ}}\cos{18^{\circ}}-\cos{30^{\circ}}\sin{18^{\circ}})^{2} \tag1\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2}\cos{18^{\circ}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin{18^{\circ}}\right)^{2} \tag2\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\cos^{2}{18^{\circ}}+\frac{3}{4}\sin^{2}{18^{\circ}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos{18^{\circ}}\sin{18^{\circ}} \tag3
\\ \\ \\
\sin^{2}{48^{\circ}}
&=\sin^{2}{(30^{\circ}+18^{\circ})} \tag4 \\
&= (\sin{30^{\circ}}\cos{18^{\circ}}+\cos{30^{\circ}}\sin{18^{\circ}})^{2} \tag5 \\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2}\cos{18^{\circ}}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin{18^{\circ}}\right)^{2} \tag6 \\
&=\frac{1}{4}\cos^{2}{18^{\circ}}+\frac{3}{4}\sin^{2}{18^{\circ}}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos{18^{\circ}}\sin{18^{\circ}} \tag7
\\ \\ \\
\sin^{2}{21^{\circ}} &=\sin^{2}{(30^{\circ}-9^{\circ})} \tag8\\
&=\left(\sin{30^{\circ}}\cos{9^{\circ}}-\cos{30^{\circ}}\sin{9^{\circ}}\right)^{2} \tag9\\ 
&=\left(\frac{1}{2}\cos{9^{\circ}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin{9^{\circ}}\right)^{2} \tag{10}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\cos^{2}{9^{\circ}}+\frac{3}{4}\sin^{2}{9^{\circ}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos{9^{\circ}}\sin{9^{\circ}} \tag{11}
\\ \\ \\
\sin^{2}{39^{\circ}}=\sin^{2}{(30^{\circ}+9^{\circ})}  
&=(\sin{30^{\circ}}\cos{9^{\circ}}+\cos{30^{\circ}}\sin{9^{\circ}})^{2} \tag{12} \\
&=(\frac{1}{2}\cos{9^{\circ}}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin{9^{\circ}})^{2} \tag{13}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\cos^{2}{9^{\circ}}+\frac{3}{4}\sin^{2}{9^{\circ}}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos{9^{\circ}}\sin{9^{\circ}} \tag{14}
\end{align}$$

So,
$$\begin{align}
\text{LHS} &=\frac{3}{2}\sin^{2}{18^{\circ}}+\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}{^18{\circ}}+\frac{3}{2}\sin^{2}{9^{\circ}}+\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2}{9^{\circ}} \tag{15}\\  
&=\sin^{2}{18^{\circ}}+sin^{2}{9^{\circ}}+\frac{1}{2}(sin^{2}{18^{\circ}}+\cos^{2}{18^{\circ}})+\frac{1}{2}(sin^{2}{9^{\circ}}+\cos^{2}{9^{\circ}}) \tag{16} \\  
&=\sin^{2}{9^{\circ}}+\sin^{2}{18^{\circ}}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \tag{17} \\   
&=1+\sin^{2}{9^{\circ}}+\sin^{2}{18^{\circ}} \tag{18} \\
&=RHS \tag{19}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I think the most obvious improvement would be to establish a general identity and then use it in the specific cases, rather than to redo the same computation four times:

$$\begin{align}
\sin^2 (x+y) + \sin^2 (x-y) 
&= (\sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y)^2 + (\sin x \cos y - \cos x \sin y)^2 \\
&= 2 \left( \sin^2 x \cos^2 y + \cos^2 x \sin^2 y \right) \tag{1} \\
\end{align}$$
so that with $x = 30^\circ$,
$$\sin^2 (30^\circ + y) + \sin^2 (30^\circ - y) = \frac{\cos^2 y + 3 \sin^2 y}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \sin^2 y. \tag{2}$$
Now substituting $y = 9^\circ$ and $y = 18^\circ$, we immediately find the LHS of the claimed identity equals
$$1 + \sin^2 9^\circ + \sin^2 18^\circ.$$

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, using that $\sin^2 \theta = \frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}$ we obtain the equivalent

$$\cos 18^\circ-\cos 24^\circ+\cos 36^\circ-\cos 42^\circ-\sin 12^\circ+\sin 6^\circ=0$$

and by sum to product identities applied to $\cos 18^\circ-\cos 24^\circ$, $\cos 36^\circ-\cos 42^\circ$ and $-\sin 12^\circ+\sin 6^\circ$ we obtain

$$\require{cancel} \cancel 2\sin 21^\circ \cancel{\sin 3^\circ}+\cancel2\sin 39^\circ \cancel{\sin 3^\circ}-\cancel2\cos 9^\circ \cancel{\sin 3^\circ} =0$$

and again by sum to product identities

$$2 \sin 30^\circ \cancel{\cos 9^\circ}-\cancel{\cos 9^\circ}=0$$

which is true.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I like the general case a lot and also the double-angle formula identity. Both very effective. Both approaches would have been taught back in the UK in 1904 so I think both are fair game.